# Integral by residue theorem where contour is a circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

The question is
$I = \int \frac{\cosh(πz)}{z(z^2+1)}dz$ where contour is the circle $|z| = 2$.

**My Working:**

So, I split the functions as $\cosh(πz)$ and $\frac{1}{z(z^2+1)}$

$I_1$ for the hyperbolic $\cos$ was $0$. (which is correct)

I calculated $I_2$ as $0$ as well. My answer is wrong even though my poles$(0,\pm i)$ were found to be correct.
[The Wolfram answer matches my working as well.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=poles%20of%201%2F%20%28z%28z%5E2%2B1%29%29)

**My Final Answer:** $I = 0$

**Answer given:** $I = 4πi$

How is my answer incorrect?

Comment: Try residues: [Residues][1]


  [1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residues%20of%20cosh%28z*pi%29%2F%20%28z%28z%5E2%2B1%29%29

Comment: But that part of the answer is already correct(it is supposed to be zero only) @arthur

Comment: The sum of the residues is $2$. Multiplied by $2\pi i$ gives $4 \pi i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say what you did that was wrong, since I don't know what you mean when you talk about splitting the integrals. But\begin{align}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\cosh(\pi z)}{z(z^2+1)}\,\mathrm dz&=2\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}_{z=-i}\frac{\cosh(\pi z)}{z(z^2+1)}+\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\frac{\cosh(\pi z)}{z(z^2+1)}+\operatorname{res}_{z=i}\frac{\cosh(\pi z)}{z(z^2+1)}\right)\\&=2\pi i\left(\frac12+1+\frac12\right)\\&=4\pi i.\end{align}

Comment: I just checked Wolfram Alpha for the whole function and the residues are indeed 2.As I mentioned in my post, I did it separately by splitting it into $cosh(πz)$  and $\frac{1}{z(z^2+1)}$, I got both of them to be 0. So I can't split them? No Poles for $cosh(πz)$ -->  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=poles+of+cosh%28pi*z%29

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I don't know what you mean when you talk about splitting those integrals. Do you mean that you computes $\int_{|z|=2}\cosh(\pi z)\,\mathrm dz$ and $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\mathrm dz}{z(z^2+1)}$?

Comment: Yes, though I should have written as I1 into I2 and not added them.